# New data to excel? pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to export data to an excel file. any help would be appreciated I keep running into errors.

The data that code is pulling and I want to export to excel:

```
 [{'Date': '07/01/2022  '}]
```

my attempt I'm trying to export to excel:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
data = [{
    'Date':soup.select_one('li.list-group-item .text-primary').text.strip()#.replace(' Date','')
}]
print (data)

datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('Dates.xlsx')
data.to_excel(datatoexcel)
datatoexcel.save()
print('DataFrame is Written to Excel Successfully.')
```

This error is popping up

```
data.to_excel AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I've also tried this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
data = [{
'Date':soup.select_one('li.list-group-item .text-primary').text.strip()#.replace(' Date','')
}]
print (data)

new_df = pd.dataframe(data)
new_df.head()
```

error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe'
```

can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe'` Use `pd.DataFrame(data)`. See [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for more detail.

Comment: @Optimus is right, adding to his comment. Check data variable datatype. Using this you will be able to determine how to read the data into data frame e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe'` because dataframe spell should be as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Once this is corrected try to export it to excel using `to_excel`:

```
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the ExcelWriter if you need a wrapper for the file you are writing to, e.g. if you want to save multiple DataFrames to multiple sheets.

For a basic case like yours you can just directly write the DataFrame to Excel. However what you created is a list of dictionaries and not a DataFrame. So you need to convert it to a DataFrame first. I assume you mean that this list can contain any number of such dicts.

```
import pandas

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
data = [{
    'Date':soup.select_one('li.list-group-item .text-primary').text.strip()
}]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel("Dates.xlsx")
print('DataFrame is Written to Excel Successfully.')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use openpyxl library for this purpose. You can create a function using following:

```
def XLSExport(Rows, SheetName, FileName):
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active
ws.title = SheetName
# ws = wb.create_sheet(SheetName)
for x in Rows:
    ws.append(x)

wb.save(FileName)
```

You can collect the data to be written in an excel with following format:

```
        ExcelExport.append([ip,card_elo['Card_ID'],card_elo['Card_Detail']['Part_Number'],card_elo['Card_Detail']['Serial_Number']])
```

As a last step, the following will help you to have your data into an excel file.

```
XLSExport(ExcelExport, "INFORMATION", "PART_SERIAL_NUMBERS.xlsx")
```